# Labelling for dynamic code references in Sphinx

Tags: python, label, python-sphinx, restructuredtext

is there the possibility to get the line number of a specific code-line in python for the sphinx documentation with .rst files?

For example with some sort of label?

```
# This program prints Hello, world!
print('Hello, world!') #LABEL#
```

Should return line 2, and

```
# This program prints Hello, world!
# Additional comment!
print('Hello, world!') #LABEL#
```

Should return line 3.

Or is there any other possibility how to get the line number of a specif part of the code?

I know the includes described in https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/1.7/markup/code.html#includes.  *start-after* and *end-before* seem to go in the right direction, but instead of citing the code, I just want to have a reference to the line.

Best regards :-)

Comment: Why would `start-after` not be what you want? In example 1, `:start-after: This program prints Hello, world!`, and example 2, `:start-after: Additional comment!` would achieve what you want. There is also `:pyobject:` if the code is a Python object.

Comment: Because I don´t want to cite the code. In the user guide, I just want to write something like: "Afterwards, the text gets printed (example.py, line 3)."